# Node.js: How to pass mongoose results to my socket.emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mongoose

My goal is to pass mongoose results (chat history) to my socket.emit.

Using the code below I get my desired database results.

```
// Find all chats.
var Chats = require('./models/chats');

Chats.find(function(err, chat_data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(chat_data);
});
```

Below this code I have my socket connection, which works like this

```
// set socket on chat
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // emit existing chats from the db
    socket.emit('chat_history', { chat_history: 'this arrives' });
```

Now the problem is: I can't figure out how to pass the mongoose results to the socket.emit. Whatever I do, mongoose is executed after the socket.emit, so I get undefined in my console.

How can I do this the proper way?

Advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the `emit` when the data is there:

```
Chats.find(function(err, chat_data) {
  socket.emit('chat_history', { chat_history: chat_data });
});
```

Comment: ah..tried something similar but that didn't work out like your fix, thanks!